# Auto-resizing div and its content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve auto resizing in my div parent block. I would like my image to resize to an exact div block width or even better if text would resize image and changes div block width so that page look neat.

```
    <body style="margin: auto;max-width: 800px">

<div class="messages" style="color: #002b55;max-width:100%;height: auto;font-size: 11px">
    <img src=cid:header.png alt="header">
    <div style="margin-top: 7px"><b>Lieber Nutzer,</b></div>
```

for example if the image is bigger than text i would like my image to resize to the longest line

[image]

Comment: Stop using inline styles. (Well, unless it's an oldschool HTMLEmail...)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I have actually created separate file for css, but when i made changes the color of the font appears to be different than the one i set for some reason

Comment: Than you need to learn about **CSS Specificity**, not write inline styles.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan when i refer refer to my css, the changes not applying even tho i did everything correctly regarding linking css,i guess that would be my other question if i wont be able to fix it

Answer (score 2):

You can have images and divs resize using `display: flex;`  Also you can have your text change size using `vw` instead of `px` such as `font-size:5vw;` which is in relation to the size of the view window.

Check out what I did here.  And here is the jsfillde for you to play around with the window size. https://jsfiddle.net/dcxp0uqe/

```css
.messages {
  width 50%;
  height 50%;
  display: flex;
  font-size:5vw;
}

.messages * {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: auto;max-width: 800px">

<div class="messages" style="">
    <img src="https://w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" alt="header">
    <div style="margin-top: 7px"><b>Lieber Nutzer,</b></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey man , thanks for your answer, my image is above the text so i want the image to be same size of the longest text basically. I have updated my question